# Using json to populate treemap of google charts

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, json, google-visualization

Hi i am using a json array of objects to get data from a mysql table , creating object of each row and adding it to json array and sending the json array to populate the treemap. But it is giving this error.

```
Uncaught Error: Every row given must be either null or an array.
```

Now, i understand that treemap uses array of arrays to populate its data, but how can i do this here as my every json object contains key value pair but treemap only needs value.i.e i want my data in this format.

```
[ ["China", 1354],["India", 1210],["United States", 315],["Canada", 35]]
```

whereas currently it is in this format.

```
[ {"country":"China","population": 1354},{"country":"India","population": 1210},{"country":"United States","population": 315},{"country":"Canada", "population":35}]
```

How to do this.Thanks.

Comment: Found the answer.Instead of putting every row in json object and then putting the object in json array , i need to put every row in a json array and put this array into another json array.

Comment: Could you put an example of the final json to populate the treemap? please